# Is there a better solution to using KeyAdapter/KeyListener for what I intend on using it for?

Tags: java, keyboard, awt, keylistener

I plan on making a chat for a game that uses Canvas, but that isn't the point, this is:
http://prntscr.com/3igt4e

As you can see, the user is holding Shift and pressing 1, this would normally produce an exclamation mark, though in this case KeyAdapter outputs a shift.

e.isShiftDown() doesn't really work. I don't really feel I want to use

if(e.isShiftDown() && [SpecificKey])

to check if every specific key is down anyways, so is there a key adapter option that automatically does this for you?

Comment: Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiple cases like:

```
case KeyEvent.VK_COMMA: return "COMMA";
case KeyEvent.VK_BRACERIGHT: return "BRACERIGHT";
```

Other options are:
**VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK**, VK_LEFT_PARENTHESIS etc. You could get a list of all such cases in any good IDE or could refer the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Comment: This wouldn't work as I use

int key = e.getKeyCode();
Game.getChat().passText(e.getKeyText(key)); 

To pass text into my String that is being displayed on the chat box.

Comment: And if I add 

   if(key == KeyEvent.VK_EXCLAMATION_MARK){
    Game.getChat().passText("!");
   }

To it after, it doesn't do a thing for some strange reason.